# MySQL Select Distinct and count number of each distinct condition matching criteria

Tags: mysql, count, match, distinct

For some reason I am having a lot of trouble with this, can someone please help me?

In MySQL, I have a table called Appointment, basic structure is below:

```
Table Appointment
Col             | Type
--------------------------
id_appointment  | int
fid_person      | int
start_time      | DATETIME
filled          | int
```

I want to be able to select all the days that appointments exist, and then count the number of appointments that are not filled on that date, so that I can output something like this:

Available Appointments

```
- 10/24/2014: 3 Appointments
- 10/25/2014: 1 Appointment
- 10/30/2014: 5 Appointments
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(start_time) as date FROM Appointment
```

Which returns me a list of all unique days, but I cannot seem to figure out the rest, I've tried a sub query but can't seem to get it right, its been a while since I've done MySQL

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just a `group by` query with conditional aggregation:

```
select date(start_time), sum(filled = 0) as NumAvailable
from Appointment
group by date(start_time)
order by date(start_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`, which automatically implies `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DATE(start_time) AS date, COUNT(*)
FROM Appointment
WHERE filled = 0
GROUP BY date
```

This will not show days with no unfilled appointments. If you want that, use Gordon Linoff's solution.